# Meteor: Get server side generated file by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, meteor, pdf-generation

I'm using `pdfKit` to generate some pdf-files. The user should click on a button to get this file - which is generated at the server at that moment. Further more I'm using `Picker` for server side routing.

**server.js**

```
Picker.route('/generate/getPdf', function(params, req, res, next) {
    var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 50});
    doc.fontSize(12);
    doc.text('PDFKit is simple', 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf'
    });
    res.end(doc.outputSync());
});
```

**html**

```
<template name="example">
    <button id="generatePdf">Generate it</button>
</template>
```

**client.js**

```
Template.example.events({
    'click #generatePdf': function(event) {
        HTTP.call( 'GET', 'http://localhost:3000/generate/getPdf', {}, function( error, response ) {
            if (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I would expect to get the pdf-file as I click on the button, but nothing is happening. If I go manually to the url, I'll get the file. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are already setting the `Content-Disposition` header to be an attachment, the easiest solution is to start the download in a new tab.

Try removing your `click #generatePdf` event handler and do something like this in your template:

```
<a id="generatePdf" href="//localhost:3000/generate/getPdf" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```